# How do you format a GET uri that uses nested complex objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, get, uri, complextype

I have the following Get API

```
public class FooController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] FooCriteria criteria) { ... }
}

public class FooCriteria
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the format of the Uri to properly pass in a nested complex type.

So far I have `http://localhost:8957/api/Foo/?Baz=hello& WHAT GOES HERE`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your url;

`http://localhost:8957/api/Foo/Get?Baz=ThisIsBaz&Location=WebApi.Controllers.FooController%2BLocation`

Modify your controller like this;

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(FooCriteria criteria)
    {          
        return new OkResult(new HttpRequestMessage());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        return View();
    }


    public class FooCriteria
    {
        public string Baz { get; set; }

        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then create two views Called Index and Get

```
@using WebApi.Controllers
@model WebApi.Controllers.FooController.FooCriteria

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}
<h2>title</h2>


@Html.ActionLink("Your GET", "Get", new FooController.FooCriteria(){Baz="ThisIsBaz", Location = new FooController.Location(){Latitude = 10, Longitude = 20}})
```

Now when you run you should be able to see what's being passed in the URL in your ActionLink